# How to get the closest indexes within a list

Tags: python

If there are two lists:

One being the items:
items = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']
The other being their indexes:
index = [0, 15, 20, 2, 16, 7, 17]

ie. The first 'A' is in index 0, the second 'A' is in index 15, etc.

How would I be able to get the closest indexes for the unique items, A, B, and C
ie. Get 15, 16, 17?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simples script. Consider those two lists as input, you just want to find the index on the letter list and it's correspondence on number list:

```
list_of_repeated=[]
list_of_closest=[]
for letter in list_letter:
    if letter in list_of_repeated:
        continue
    else:
        list_of_repeated.append(letter)
        list_of_closest.append(list_number[list_letter.index(letter)])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is minimize the sum of differences between indices.

You can find the minimal combination like this:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

items = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']
index = [0, 15, 20, 2, 16, 7, 17]

cost = np.inf
for combination in product(*[list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == i, zip(items, index))) for i in set(items)]):
    diff = sum(abs(np.ediff1d([i[1] for i in combination])))
    if diff < cost:
        cost = diff
        idx = combination
print(idx)
```

This is bruteforcing the solution, there may be more elegant / faster ways to do this, but this is what comes to my mind on the fly.